# How to use set_token in mapdeck?

Tags: r, mapdeck

I'm trying to reproduce this example: https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck, using mapdeck r package.

I registered myself on mapbox site and create my token. 
Whenever I run my script there is no error, but there is no map either.

```
library(mapdeck)
library(leaflet)

key <- set_token("pk.eyJ1IjoicmFxdWVsc2FyYWl2YTE5ODgiLCJhIjoiY2p4MzM2eHh5MG95aTN5cDQxdjVocDlxMCJ9.Wskus8QqYwjAufGpW71OVg")

df <- readRDS("df.rds")

df$Station_Long = as.numeric(as.character(df$lon_Pay))
df$Station_Lat = as.numeric(as.character(df$lat_Pay))
df$id = as.factor(as.numeric(as.factor(df$ID)))

mapdeck(
  token = key,
  style = mapdeck_style('dark')
  , location = c(104, 1)
  , zoom = 8
  , pitch = 45
) %>%
  add_arc(
    data = df
    , origin = c("centroid_lon", "centroid_lat")
    , destination = c("lon_Pay", "lat_Pay")
    , layer_id = 'arclayer'
    , stroke_width = 3
    , stroke_from = "#ccffff"
    , stroke_to = "#ccffff"
  )
```

My key is NULL (empty).

Does anybody knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `set_token()` you don't assign it to a variable, you just call it.

```
library(mapdeck)

set_token( "YOUR_MAPOBX_TOKEN" )
```

It's then stored globally in your session

```
## view your token
mapdeck_tokens()

# Mapdeck tokens
# -  mapbox : YOUR_MAPBOX_TOKEN
```

Using `set_token()` means you don't have to supply the `token` argument in the `mapdeck()` call

```
url <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_february_aa_flight_paths.csv'
flights <- read.csv(url)
flights$id <- seq_len(nrow(flights))
flights$stroke <- sample(1:3, size = nrow(flights), replace = T)
flights$info <- paste0("<b>",flights$airport1, " - ", flights$airport2, "</b>")

mapdeck( style = mapdeck_style("dark"), pitch = 45 ) %>%
  add_arc(
    data = flights
    , layer_id = "arc_layer"
    , origin = c("start_lon", "start_lat")
    , destination = c("end_lon", "end_lat")
    , stroke_from = "airport1"
    , stroke_to = "airport2"
    , stroke_width = "stroke"
    , tooltip = "info"
    , auto_highlight = TRUE
    , legend = T
    , legend_options = list(
      stroke_from = list( title = "Origin airport" ),
      css = "max-height: 100px;")
   )
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, SymbolixAU. I did it and the result is the same, a blank page, I mean, theres no map in there.

Comment: What do you see when you call `mapdeck_tokens()`?

Comment: ok. You may now want to delete that comment because you've exposed your key. What happens when you go `mapdeck()`

Comment: sorry, you're right. It shows a blank page. No map in there.

Comment: Please try some of the suggestions [at this link](https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/issues.html)

Comment: @R.Saraiva did any of the information at the link give you a solution?

Comment: unfortunately no. I still have the same issue. But thank you for your help.

Comment: If you want to dive into this further you can open an issue on the [issues page](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck/issues) and we can try and work through the problem.